# ios api or class for picture zone action based mapping?

Tags: ios

I am looking to have zonal click action in iOS for an image that is loaded in an application. For example a picture of a dog is loaded and you click on its head.  This would link to an action of your choice such as opening another class or an action.  Another action would occur click on the dogs leg and it open another link/class/action etc...

I would imagine that you designate a range or a zone trigger in a picture to accomplish this.

I have tried to look for a standard class or api but I haven't had much luck in finding what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the image in a `UIImageView`, enable user interaction on the view' add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view. When you get the action method callback from the gesture you can check the location of the tap against your configuration rectangles to decide what to do.